# Wishlist item Always Return 3 items

Tags: magento2, jquery

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 
    'domReady'
], function ($, Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        var _this = this;
        
        this._super();
        
        this.wishlist = customerData.get('wishlist');
        console.log(this.wishlist);
        this.wishlist.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            _this.decorateItems();
        });

        _this.decorateItems();
    },
    
    decorateItems: function() {
            var items = this.wishlist().items;
        
            if (typeof items === 'undefined' || !items.length) return;
        
            $('a.action.towishlist').each(function(){
                    var data = $(this).data('post'),
                        i;

                    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if (data.data.product == items[i].product_id) {
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                            $(this).css("pointer-events","none");
                            console.log(items[i].product_id); 
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
});
});
```

above is my code to get customer wishlist item in js but its always return last 3 items even there is 6 items in wishlist but this script showing only 3 items

i also treid change
namespace Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData;
const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;
and change it to 6 but nothing happend?